# How to view the sent mails in Mutt?

Tags: email, mutt

I executed the "mutt" command and it only showed me the inbox mails.

How should I view the sent emails? If I want to send a new mail against the first delivered mail, how should I do it?

I added set record=+outbox in the .muttrc file but it didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1: If your sent message folder is "outbox" (I assume you are using Maildir format for mail, so actual path is `~/Maildir/outbox`), then you can start `mutt` with the command:

```
mutt -f ~/Maildir/outbox
```

or

```
mutt -f =outbox
```

(`=` is a shortcut used by `mutt` to indicate a subfolder of your Maildir)

Option 2: When viewing inbox, press the `c` key. If your `mutt` is properly configured you should see a list of folders in your Maildir. Select the folder you want and press Enter.

I don't understand what do you mean by "send a new mail against the first delivered mail"? Do you mean **reply** to the received mail? If yes, this is done by pressing the `r` key on that mail.